# Staged training of Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

From what the documentation says about `NetTrain` and `NetInitialize` and what the progress indicator shows when reevaluating examples from the Documentation it looks like `NetTrain` **always** calls `NetInitialize`.

The *Properties & Relations* section of `NetInitialize` states

> NetTrain will automatically call NetInitialize before training begins. The weights and biases of a simple layer are initialized before training

Can someone confirm this behavior and if so offer a workaround? It would be really useful to be able to train networks in stages for instance for pre-training a network on some readily available (similar) data or for playing around with [Complementary Reinforcement Backpropagation](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~meeden/DevelopmentalRobotics/AckleyLittman90.ps).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So actually this is already implied by the documentation for `NetInitialize`, which says "gives a net in which all **uninitialized** learnable parameters in net have been given initial values". So when you retrain, you're starting with weights, and the internal `NetInitialize` does nothing (you can use the second argument of 'All' to *force* it to overwrite existing weights).

But in any case I've added a note to `NetTrain` to mention that it doesn't re-initialize pre-existing weights. Thanks for drawing my attention to this possible confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I played around more with this and found my initial observation that `NetTrain` starts anew each time to be wrong!

Take for instance the *MNIST example* from the `NetTrain`>>*Applications*>>*Image Classification*- section. There replace the line

```
lenet = NetTrain[lenet, trainingData, ValidationSet -> testData, 
MaxTrainingRounds -> 3]
```

with

```
(lenet = NetTrain[lenet, RandomSample[trainingData, 100], 
 BatchSize -> 10, MaxTrainingRounds -> 1]) //Do[#, 10^3]&
```

and observe that indeed the network learns when increasing the number of rounds via `Do` or repeatedly evaluating this line. The following lines, also found in that example, can be used to check classification accuracy against the test set.

```
cm = ClassifierMeasurements[lenet, testData]
cm["Accuracy"]
```

Comment: you should be aware that by doing this you'll be losing the internal state used by the optimizers, so training will be less stable and efficient.

Luckily, for 11.1 they'll be a nice internal API to do your own staged training with zero overhead using a "Trainer" object. You could use it for quite complex stuff that isn't possible to parameterize under NetTrain.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon Thank you for your answer and comment! Can you tell me wether this "Trainer"-object stuff will also support some flavor of Reinforcement learning (in the future)? I just recently tried the algorithm from the paper I linked in my question and it seems to work well for easy problems (MNIST with only 0's and 1's) but implementing it is not as comfortable as one might wish. To be able and assign a critic/feedback system to a trainer would be really convenient.

Comment: we intend to support reinforcement learning at some point. The state of the art with experience replay etc in is quite complicated and would probably require a new function (not NetTrain). But trainers will be quite general, you define which ports provide the loss (or a custom function to impose the final loss gradient to be backpropogated), feed them batches of training data, and then they do the forward and backward pass and update the weights via the optimizers. NetTrain will just do the 'feeding' in a Do loop, basically.